# AMD GPU crashing when playing game

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, amdgpu, mesa

I have a problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I recently upgraded my GPU to a RX 580 from a GTX 960, but now it seems to crash every time I've played a game for a bit. This time interval isn't consistant, it can vary from after a few minutes up to an hour. When the crash happens, the screen freezes, but the rest of the system is still running. I can still do stuff like REISUB and SSH into the machine.

My kernel version is 4.15.0-51-generic and my graphics driver is X.Org Radeon RX 580 Series (POLARIS10, DRM 3.23.0, 4.15.0-51-generic, LLVM 7.0.0) Version 4.4 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 18.2.8.

I have tested some games, and here is the ones I have found to be crashing: Hearts Of Iron IV, Starcraft (Running on WINE), XCOM 2, Dirt Rally and Project Cars 2 (Running on Proton). I have also not been able to make Minecraft or Rimworld crash. I don't know if this will help, but here you go.

Things I've tried so far include removeing the nvidia driver, reinstalling the mesa-vulkan-driver and ubuntu-desktop, but this didn't help with the issue. Can anyone recommend any solutions? The graphics card isn't overheating either, running below 70 degrees at all time.
Thank you for any answers!

Edit: I recreated the issue and extracted this from the syslog file in /var/log from the minuttes around the crash: https://pastebin.com/5pgnV0R1

Comment: sorry but assuming the amd gpu crashing is a bot of a stretch from this alone. Wine and proton you should not rely on for analysis.  It would be far more logical for wine and proton to not have 100% compatibility for your graphics card  and you running into a software issue. heck if  the gpu crashes how do you see yourself still using ssh to connect? " Can anyone recommend any solutions?" where are the log files of the crahes and why are these not included into the question?!

Comment: You're correct that I'm not actually sure that the problem is the GPU crashing, but since the symptoms was the screen freezing, I assumed this was it. I don't think it is a software problem, because it happens with games which I'm not using WINE to run. What I ment be using SSH to connect, is I can still interact with the system, install and uninstall and stuff like. Also after I reboot the PC, I can see the commands I ran through SSH in the terminal.

Comment: I would recommend switching to the HWE stack, which will get you upgraded to 4.18 kernel and newer Xorg/Mesa.